# TypeError: 'User' object is not subscriptable while trying to create specific list

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, list-comprehension

I trying to query some data and it returns a list of Object.
Trying just to extract the email and create a list but encountering type error.
Wondering what is the correct approach in doing it, currently my method is not working.

Let say:

emails=User.query.filter_by(approver=True).all()

Returns:

[User('superuser','hoosk1@gmail.com','0bf35e27606e7418.jpg'), User('approver','approve@test.com','c33f6a6bc4e350b0.jpg'), User('approver2','approver2@gmail.com','defualt.jpg'), User('approver3','approver3@gmail.com','defualt.jpg'), User('chrishoosk','chrishoosk@gmail.com','default.jpg')]

I trying to get the email and created a list.

Having try

to_send=[mail for mail in emails]

Returns:
TypeError: 'User' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the error will be starting from here

```py
to_send=[mail for mail in emails]
```

You will want to access a property on the objects you are iterating through

```py
to_send=[user.mail for user in emails]
```

This will give you a list of email addresses rather than a list of `User` objects (providing `mail` is a valid property of a `User` object).

Comment: thanks !! it working now. Although I still do not understand about the object properties concept, guess  I have to figure it out.